# synchronous call in mobile jquery and phoneGap to get data from database

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

```
i have written code to get max data from database and then insert that data in another table but it is not giving data first time.it is giving leadid as undefined because it is not waiting result of getMaxLeadId and executing second statement.my code is given below

var  leadId = getMaxLeadId();

alert("leadId"+leadId);

function getMaxLeadId() {}
```

and

```
function getMaxIdData_success(tx, result){}
```

after I  need to call insert `maxLeadId` into insert function.

Please suggest me some      idea how to write callback function in java Script.

Answer (score 3):

The common way to do this is with callbacks in a style of programming known as [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

The general form of this is

```
var doSomeCalc = function(resultFunc) {
    //do some long running calc
    var result = 4;

    resultFunc(result);
};

var writeOutResult = function(result) {
    console.log(result);
};

doSomeCalc(writeOutResult);
```

so you will want to write your getMaxLeadId() in this form to take the callback then should be called when it has calculated the answer.

Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if you think it is.